# AngularUI Bootstrap typeahead showing "No Results" instead of drop down objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-options, angular-ui-typeahead

My AngularUI bootstrap typeahead is returning "No Results Found" even though it should be reading through an array of Objects.

in uib-typeahead I have `uib-typeahead="number for number in getNumbers($viewValue)"`

and in my controller I have

```
$scope.getNumbers = function($viewValue) {

...stuff to retrieve numbers...

return array
}
```

where `console.log(array)` shows [Object, Object, Object...]

I'm just trying to show the bits of code that I think are relevant. Is this where the problem is? Why is the dropdown returning No Results found?

```
                       <input
                       type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="number"
                       ng-model="numberinfo.number"
                       uib-typeahead="number for number in getNumbers($viewValue)"
                       typeahead-template-url="/tpl.html"
                       typeahead-loading="Loadinglocations"
                       typeahead-on-select="numberSelect($item, 10)"
                       typeahead-wait-ms="3"
                           typeahead-min-length="3"
                           typeahead-no-results="noResults"
                           required>
                    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">Loading...</i>
             <div ng-show="noResults">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found.
             </div>



<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    <a>
        <div>
            <span style="display:block;" class="registration"
                  ng-bind-html="match.model.number | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try to elaborate your question creating a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) so that we can see the problem you have?

Comment: can you show some controller code ?

Answer (score 0):

your controller is consoling the object but your uib-typehead is not getting it its could be because of this parameter

```
$scope.getNumbers = function($viewValue)
```

change it to

```
$scope.getNumbers = function(viewValue)
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. The output is the same and the "No Results Found" message still shows up.

Comment: Than I guess u'll have to make a plunker to understand ur controllrr code, i hope u'll get the answer after that